# Append ndarry as pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm attempting to create a pandas dataframe which contains a single column of numpy numeric arrays.

I attempt to use :

```
pd.DataFrame(np.ndarray([1 , 2]))
```

Which creates a pandas dataframe of two columns.

I've also attempted to use :

```
pd.DataFrame({'test':np.ndarray([1 , 2])})
```

but returns error :

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in extract_index(data)
   5631 
   5632         if not indexes and not raw_lengths:
-> 5633             raise ValueError('If using all scalar values, you must pass'
   5634                              ' an index')
   5635 

ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(np.ndarray([2 , 1]))` ?

Comment: One column pandas is called Series: pd.Series([1 , 2]).rename('test')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC:

There are several ways to do this.  You could do it by passing a **`list`** of arrays.

```
pd.DataFrame({'test':[np.array([1 , 2])]})

     test
0  [1, 2]
```

Simple generalization for column of lists

```
df = pd.Series(np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]]).tolist()).to_frame('test')    
df

     test
0  [1, 2]
1  [3, 4]
```

And column of `np.array`

```
df = pd.Series(np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]]).tolist()).apply(np.array).to_frame('test')
df

     test
0  [1, 2]
1  [3, 4]
```

Or you can do more.  This will be a DataFrame where the elements are `np.array`

```
df = pd.Series(
    [np.array(v) for v in np.random.randint(10, size=(10, 3)).tolist()]
).to_frame('test')
df

        test
0  [3, 1, 5]
1  [8, 3, 7]
2  [1, 8, 6]
3  [3, 1, 7]
4  [6, 2, 7]
5  [1, 0, 8]
6  [8, 8, 0]
7  [6, 6, 7]
8  [4, 0, 9]
9  [5, 2, 1]
```

Notice the types

```
df.applymap(type)

                      test
0  <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
1  <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
2  <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
3  <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
4  <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
5  <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
6  <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
7  <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
8  <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
9  <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

However, we could also skip the `np.array` by passing a list of lists.

```
df = pd.Series(np.random.randint(10, size=(10, 3)).tolist()).to_frame('test')
df

        test
0  [3, 1, 5]
1  [8, 3, 7]
2  [1, 8, 6]
3  [3, 1, 7]
4  [6, 2, 7]
5  [1, 0, 8]
6  [8, 8, 0]
7  [6, 6, 7]
8  [4, 0, 9]
9  [5, 2, 1]
```

Notice the types

```
df.applymap(type)

             test
0  <class 'list'>
1  <class 'list'>
2  <class 'list'>
3  <class 'list'>
4  <class 'list'>
5  <class 'list'>
6  <class 'list'>
7  <class 'list'>
8  <class 'list'>
9  <class 'list'>
```

Comment: Let me know if this is what you were looking for.  Otherwise, I'll delete this.

Comment: to add multiple rows should this generalize to ' pd.DataFrame({'test':[np.array([[1 , 2] , [3,4]])]}) ' or is a Series required ?

Comment: I show you how to generalize.  You don't need to wrap it in `[]` but use `.tolist()`